# How does C# know how to correctly modify namespace for it to work?

Tags: c#, namespaces

How does C# know how to correctly modify namespace for it to work?

Recently I come across a seemingly simple concept, but I was struck by my lack of a clear understanding of what is going on. And a simple googling did not help me to get a better picture. So, I am making the question.

I have a project with two files:

**File1.cs**

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    using E.F;

    public class D 
    {
        G g;
    }
}
```

**File2.cs**

```
namespace A.B.E.F
{
    public class G { }
}
```

Now before my coworker pointed this out, I never met this, even though I read a few in depth books on C# and have a quite long experience working with C#. So, here the C# parser does a pretty clever thing. He takes the `using E.F;` from the **File1.cs**, takes the enclosing namespaces (i.e. the `namespace A.B.C`), removes the `C` from the enclosing namespace and adds the `E.F` to the remaining namespace part. Getting the `using A.B.E.F` in the end.

The modification does not seem trivial for me at all. The compiler should now how many trailing namespaces to remove from the `A.B.C` (in this case 1 - that is `C`), so that the addition of the `E.F` would lead to a namespace containing the `class G`.

Now I am asking if my understanding of what is happening is correct and where could I read about these modifications a compiler does?

**UPDATE**

If we take the following files:

**File1.cs**

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    using E.F;

    public class D 
    {
        G g;
    }
}
```

**File2.cs**

```
namespace A.B.E.F
{
    public class G { }
}

namespace E.F
{

}
```

The compiler will still be able to locate exactly the `A.B.E.F` in the **File1.cs** in the `using E.F;` line and not the `E.F`. So, the compiler is not simply looking for the `E.F` namespace as was pointed out in comments, but it looks for such `E.F` which would contain the `class G`. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

**UPDATE 2**

The comment which points to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#namespace-and-type-names) (from the @Damien_The_Unbeliever) documentation made me think about the first versions of the **File1.cs** and **File2.cs**. In some sense the result they produce looks like that:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            using E.F;

            public class D
            {
                G g;
            }
        }

        namespace E
        {
            namespace F
            {
                public class G { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can move the `using E.F` up through the namespaces chain. The namespace `E.F` is defined starting with the namespace `A.B`, so the following is legit:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        using E.F;

        namespace C
        {
            public class D
            {
                G g;
            }
        }

        namespace E
        {
            namespace F
            {
                public class G { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While the following is not legit, because in namespace `A` we still do not know about the `E.F` namespace:

```
namespace A
{
    using E.F;

    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            public class D
            {
                G g;
            }
        }

        namespace E
        {
            namespace F
            {
                public class G { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, we know about the `B.E.F` namespace in the namespace `A`, so the following is legit:

```
namespace A
{
    using B.E.F;

    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            public class D
            {
                G g;
            }
        }

        namespace E
        {
            namespace F
            {
                public class G { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, my guess is that my first assumption about the C# computing the namespaces was wrong. And actually C# does not compute namespaces, but just knows a set of namespaces in each given namespace. And some namespaces may have more than one name in some cases. E.g. the `A.B.E.F` namespace has the following names inside the `A.B` namespace: `A.B.E.F`, `B.E.F`, `E.F`. All of the 3 namespace names point to a same namespace. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Maybe there is some backtracking involved in walking up and down the namespace tree until a common root?

Comment: @UweKeim, I am more surprised not about the existence of such an algorithm, but about my lack of exposure to the topic. Virtually not a single book, tutorial or article I come across did not consider the topic. :)

Comment: The compiler is simply trying to locate the `E` namespace and finds it in `A.B.E`.

Comment: Yep, it walks up the tree until it finds `E`. Compare to https://dotnetfiddle.net/FGBCgA / https://dotnetfiddle.net/NfAds5

Comment: [Namespace and type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#namespace-and-type-names) describes the algorithm employed. Look under the "If the previous steps were unsuccessful then, for each namespace N, starting with the namespace in which the namespace_or_type_name occurs, continuing with each enclosing namespace (if any), and ending with the global namespace, the following steps are evaluated until an entity is located" section

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: `but it looks for such E.F which would contain the class G` I suspect it looks for E, then F, then G. Hence why https://dotnetfiddle.net/NfAds5 doesn't work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, seems what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Is "Update 2" the answer?

Comment: @Sinatr, I am not sure. I need someone more experienced than me to check my understanding, possibly correct it and say what I missed or if what I wrote is correct at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, why is that specification is kind of too hard to read? Like it is written really very abstract and that makes it hard to grasp. :)

Comment: The specification aims to be *precise*. It's trying not to leave gaps and the mountains of *undefined behaviour* that some other languages have ended up with.